# Using wildcard in Gradle Files then copy if it exists

Tags: gradle

In very brief, I want to find all files that ends with *.sql and copy them if they exist.
There might be 0 or more files in etc directory.

```
    File sqlfiles = file('etc/' + '*.sql')
    logger.info("Looking for SQL files: " + sqlfiles);
    if (sqlfiles.exists())
    {
        logger.info("Found log SQL file: " + sqlfiles);

        copy
                {
                    from sqlfiles
                    into "$rpmStoredir"
                }
    }
    else
    {
        logger.warn("No SQL file found - skipping");
    }
```

With my code, the wildcard is not working here.

So adding "include" to the copy as in the below is working but I just want to figure how to add a logger if the file does not exist

```
copy
{
    from "etc/"
    include "*.sql"
    into "$rpmStoredir"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`file(...)` is the wrong method to use as this returns a single `java.io.File`

You could do something like

```
FileTree myTree = fileTree('etc') {
   include '*.sql'
}
if (myTree.empty) {
  ... 
} else {
   copy {
      from myTree
      ... 
   } 
}
```

See [Project.fileTree(Object, Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#fileTree-java.lang.Object-groovy.lang.Closure-) and [FileTree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html)